# Что такое параметры в нейронных сетях?

Tags: нейронные-сети, параметры

Говорят, в gpt-3 аж 175 млрд параметров, а в gpt-2 было лишь 1,5 млрд.

Так вот, дайте пожалуйста развёрнутое объяснение - что такое эти самые параметры в нейронных сетях? Что это значит? И какие выводы можно из этого сделать?

Comment: Пример параметров - веса входов нейронов. Теоретически нейросеть с большим количеством параметров более гибкая, "лучше" обучается (но не факт - большое значение имеет архитектура сети, однослойная сеть с миллиардами параметров вам много не нараспознает). Считайте что это условные "попугаи", количеством которых хотят показать "крутость" нейросети.

Comment: @insolor, «крутость» измеряется качеством предсказания, а огромное число параметров - это ужасные тормоза и прямой путь к переобучению ;)

Comment: @MaxU, согласен, поэтому и написал "хотят показать", а не "показывает")

Comment: Про Гугл я конечно в курсе, раз уж я что-то на so спросил. Я видел во всяких обзорах, что параметры условно отражают крутость нейронных сетей. Только вот я так и не нашёл внятного ответа - что именно называется этими параметрами? Что они делают? И почему это они отражают крутость нейронной сети? Это нейроны или что? Что это вообще за фигня. Почему-то на какой-нибудь Википедии нет простого описания. Мол: "Параметры в нейронных сетях - это то-то-то... От них зависит то-то и то-то. Из чего можно сделать такие-то выводы."

Comment: @DerianDeGrey, в процессе обучения нейросети настраиваются веса входов нейронов. Это и есть параметры.

Comment: @DerianDeGrey "Это нейроны или что" в каком-то смысле да, но надо понимать, что нейроны бывают разные по сути, и нейросети бывают разной архитектуры, поэтому там всё смешано в одну кучу и однозначно сказать, чему эти параметры принадлежат, наверное, нельзя. Это просто показатель сложности нейросети в условных весах "нейронов", да. Но у одного блока нейросети может быть не один вес, а несколько (как в LSTM), поэтому в нейронах если считать, будут одни цифры, в блоках - другие. Не все веса в блоке одинаково полезны, опять же.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Теперь стало яснее.